# Drupal Ajax pager

Tags: forms, ajax, paging

Am looking for a solution to implement `$form['pager'] = ['#type' => 'pager'];` into AJAX callback (without reloading the page). I have read alot of posts concluding there is no a drupal way to do this at the moment but on visiting this drupal page: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements it actually implements it. How do i get such results.

## My Code

```
class TableAjaxPager extends FormBase{

    $query = \Drupal::database()->select('users_field_data', 'u');
    $query->fields('u', ['uid','name','mail']);
    //For the pagination we need to extend the pagerselectextender and
    //limit in the query
    $pager = $query->extend('Drupal\Core\Database\Query\PagerSelectExtender')->limit(10);
    $results = $pager->execute()->fetchAll();



// Initialize an empty array
$output = array();
// Next, loop through the $results array
 foreach ($results as $result) {
      if ($result->uid != 0 && $result->uid != 1) {
        $output[$result->uid] = [
          'userid' => $result->uid,            // 'userid' was the key used in the header
          'Username' => $result->name, // 'Username' was the key used in the header
          'email' => $result->mail, // 'email' was the key used in the header
        ];
      }
    }



   $form['table'] = [
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#options' => $output,
      '#empty' => t('No users found'),
    ];
  // Finally add the pager.
    $form['pager'] = array(
      '#type' => 'pager'
    );
    return $form;
}
```

Comment: Are you building a form through `buildForm` **OR** altering an existing form

Comment: @ Razeem Ahmad yes

Comment: @Razeem Ahmad have updated my code.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but still no solution, just happy I'm not the only one. You're revering to '/api/drupal/elements' but it seams that the page is using /views/ajax so it's a views page. Maybe we're able to use the views ajax call or the views pager. Going to try it out.